# How to show url for individual citations in biblatex-chicago?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, biblatex-chicago

I use the `includeall=false` option in `biblatex-chicago`. While this suppresses items I don't want to show up in my footnotes, it also has the effect of suppressing url's when I do want them to show up. In the case of the MWE below what I would like to be able to do is leave the global option on so url won't show for book1 citation but be able to show url for Nazzal2005 citation both in the footnote and bibliography.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, includeall=false,]{biblatex-chicago} %Sets Bibliography style.
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
address = {Anytown},
booktitle = {Example book},
pages = {5},
title = {{Any book you want}},
url = {http://www.amazon.com},
year = {2000}
}
@article{EPost11/12/1915,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
address = {Wellington},
journal = {Evening Post},
keywords = {primary},
day = {11},
month = dec,
pages = {5},
title = {{Exiled Samoans}},
year = {1915}
}
@misc{Nazzal2005,
author = {Nazzal, Mary},
number = {April},
title = {{Nauru : An Environment Destroyed and International Law}},
url = {http://www.lawanddevelopment.org/articles/nauru.html},
urldate = {2014-03-18},
year = {2005}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname} % if you’re using biblatex
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\autocite{Nazzal2005}

\lipsum[1]\autocite{EPost11/12/1915}

\lipsum[1]\autocite{book1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
\newbibmacro*{bib+doi+url}{% 16th ed.
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}%
    {}%
    {\printurldate}% Date fix
  \iffieldundef{addendum}% Punctuation fixes in 0.9.9c
    { \newunit\newblock}%
    {\newcunit\newblock}%
  \iftoggle{cms@doionly}%
    {\iffieldundef{doi}%
       {}%
       {\printfield{doi}%
        \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock%
        \clearfield{url}}}%
    {\ifboolexpr{%
        togl {cms@doi}%
        and
        not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}%
     }%
       {\printfield{doi}%
        \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock}%
       {}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@eprint}%
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{eprint}}%
  }%
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}%
     \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock}%
    {}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    (togl {cms@url} or test {\ifentrytype{misc}})
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{url}}%
  }%
    {\printfield{url}}%
    {}}%

\newbibmacro*{cite+doi+url}{% 16th ed.
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}%
    {}%
    {\printurldate}% Date fix
  \newcunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@doionly}%
    {\iffieldundef{doi}%
       {}%
       {\printfield{doi}%
        \clearfield{url}}}%
    {\ifboolexpr{%
      togl {cms@doi}%
      and
      not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}%
     }%
       {\printfield{doi}}%
       {}}%
  \newcunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@eprint}%
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{eprint}}%
  }%
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}%
    {}%
  \newcunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{%
    (togl {cms@url} or test {\ifentrytype{misc}})
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{url}}%
  }%
    {\printfield{url}}%
    {}}%
```

Which effectively makes `@misc` entries ignore the `cms@url` toggle which is set to false by `includeall=false`. You can add any other types you like, for example `@online` to always have their URL printed by replacing `(togl {cms@url} or test {\ifentrytype{misc}})` with

```
(togl {cms@url} or test {\ifentrytype{misc}} or test {\ifentrytype{online}})
```

---

Alternatively, we can go for `includeall=true` instead and delete the URL where you don't want it.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{misc}{}{\clearfield{url}}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifentrytype{misc}{}{\clearfield{url}}}
```

If you want this for more types, go with

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{misc}} or test {\ifentrytype{online}}}
    {}
    {\clearfield{url}}}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{misc}} or test {\ifentrytype{online}}}
    {}
    {\clearfield{url}}}
```

to specify where you want to keep the URL, or with

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} or test {\ifentrytype{book}}}
    {\clearfield{url}}
    {}}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} or test {\ifentrytype{book}}}
    {\clearfield{url}}
    {}}
```

to specify where to delete the URL.

Comment: In the last solutions for mulitple types what does the `\ifboolexpr` mean and does the text "test" and "or test" do anything?

Comment: @gman `\ifboolxepr` is an [`etoolbox`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) command that allows to combine several `\if...` expressions into one. The `\if...` commands then need to be wrapped in braces and must be prefixed by `test` for `etoolbox` to treat them correctly. See pp. 23-27 of the [`etoolbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf).